# Download site and all embedded content with Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, ghost.py

The [Ghost.py](https://github.com/jeanphix/Ghost.py) headless browser allows you to download both a page's source code as well as the all of the embedded content associated with it (ie. JavaScript, images, CSS, etc.). Is it possible to do this with Selenium?

Comment: you will have to extract all links from HTML code and download them.

Comment: why not just use a curl for this task?   Selenium is designed for "automating manual tasks in the browser"..

Comment: @sircapsalot, I'm looking at a number of sites that dynamically change the page with JS. I'd like to use Ghost.py, but it has a couple of bugs and I was hoping for a nice alternative in Selenium.